# Is there a way to reproduce this type of sequence in Latex?

Tags: latex

I need to reproduce this sequence

[image]

in a Latex document.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackrel}

\begin{document}

\[
a \, b \vdash \stackrel[b]{a}{\vert} , \stackrel[a]{b}{\vert} 
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have 3 letter connected vertically as in the image you provided? Like a-b-c (vertically) without having them to shrink in font-size?

Comment: @zBION1C For anything more complicate than two letters, I suggest to have a look at the TikZ package. It will be slower, but you will have full control over positioning etc.